# Exposing AngularJS directive property value to parent controller

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an AngularJS app. I am trying to write a reusable component to use throughout my app. For the sake of demonstration, we'll just use a text box. I've created a fiddle of my [attempt here](http://jsfiddle.net/dfcqtdju/). Basically, I'm trying to use a control like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
      <my-control textValue="{{controlValue}}"></my-control>
      <br />
      You entered: {{controlValue}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to bind a property between the scope of the controller and the scope of the directive. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfcqtdju/). Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not so far, but you need to be carefull when using {{}}

Remove braces and don't use camelNotation for text-value attribute :

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
      <my-control text-value="controlValue"></my-control>
      <br />
      You entered: {{controlValue}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Use ng-model attribute :

```
angular.module('ui.directives', []).directive('myControl',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EAC',

      scope: {
          textValue: '='
      },
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="textValue"></input>'
    };
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created directive with isolated scope and you are trying to print value from isolate scope. It isn't right, you can write your directive like this, without isolated [scope](http://jsfiddle.net/dfcqtdju/1/):

```
 return {
      restrict: 'EAC',

        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="controlValue"></input>'
    };
```

if you want to setup directive with isolated scope, you should isolate your scope then use $watch for do changes